# select values from DataTable column where not in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code :

```
List<long> LevelsArray = CardServiceDetailsDt.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Select(r => r.Field<long("LEVEL_ID"))
                                 .ToList<long>(); 

DataTable leveldt =ClientsDataHelper.GetServicePackagesLevel(new WebSiteDataHelper()
                                 .SelectedStoreID.Value);
```

how can I select the `LEVEL_ID` from which are not in the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asssuming that the second table also has the column `LEVEL_ID`:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> filteredRows = leveldt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => !LevelsArray.Contains(r.Field<long>("LEVEL_ID")));
```

Here's a probably more efficient Linq Left-Outer-Join appproach

```
filteredRows  = from row in leveldt.AsEnumerable()
                join levelID in LevelsArray
                on row.Field<long>("LEVEL_ID") equals levelID into rowLevelID
                from subrow in rowLevelID.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where subrow == null
                select row;
```

If you only need the ID's which are not in the list, use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<long> notInList = leveldt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<long>("LEVEL_ID"))
    .Except(LevelsArray)
    .ToList();
```

which is the most efficient approach since it's using a set. It select only the ID's from the datarows which are not in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<long> LevelsArray = (from r in leveldt.AsEnumerable()
         let LEVEL_ID = r.Field<long>("LEVEL_ID")
         where !list.Contains(LEVEL_ID)
         select LEVEL_ID).ToList<long>();
```